# In ruby, what is the vocab word for `attr_accessor`?

Tags: ruby, terminology

In Ruby, you can add `attr_reader`, `attr_writer` or `attr_accessor` to a class to generate accessors and mutators for an instance variable. In Rails, model validations and controller filters are added using a similar syntax.

I know that under the hood this is a method that runs when the class is defined, which generates some code and attaches it to the class.

What I'm looking for is a **vocab word** to describe this pattern. My searching has come up with "[code ]generator" and "helper", and I think I like "generator" the best, but I wonder if there is an official word for it.

Sources:

- https://mikeyhogarth.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/creating-your-own-attr_accessor-in-ruby/
- http://codeatmorning.com/ruby-attr_accessor-what-is-that/

Comment: I have never heard of [Module#attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor), [Module#define_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) and other Ruby methods that generate methods referred to as anything other than just `methods`. Moreover, I don't see that advantage of having such a term, especially because I don't see how it could be defined in an  unambiguous way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When code generates or expands into other code, it can be called a macro.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science)

Comment: Yep, I've always called these “class macros” specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The book "The Ruby Programming Language" (Flanagan, [Matsumoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto)) refers to it as metaprogramming (pg. 219)